# Get frame's position at an specific rate per second

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to get the current position of `camera` in scene adding a renderer delegate method (a method in ARSCNViewDelegate):

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {

    guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }
    let transform = pointOfView.transform
    let position = SCNVector3Make(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43)
    let orientation = SCNVector3Make(transform.m31, transform.m32, transform.m33)
    ...
}
```

And I would like to get these positions for a specific number of frames per second (25 fps in my case). I can get this by modifying this parameter: [preferredFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/1648421-preferredframespersecond) but it always adjusts automatically to 30 fps, not 25.
It works ok for 5, 15, 20, 30, 45 or 60, but why not for 25 fps?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    sceneView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 25
    ...
}
```

Anyway, of course reducing FPS means poorer AR performance so... is there another way to ask ARKit for a frame camera position each time I need one? specifically every 25 fps.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: if you have not thought of it, you can use thread to get update every 1/25 seconds and get your position

Comment: Hi @alok-subedi, how can I implement that? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used to run block of code after certain time in second. (1/25 in your case)

```
func recurringFunction(){
    // your code here
    guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }
    let transform = pointOfView.transform
    let position = SCNVector3Make(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43)
    let orientation = SCNVector3Make(transform.m31, transform.m32, transform.m33)
    ....

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1/25) {
        self.recurringFunction()
    }
}
```

It will also help in running your app without dropping your usual fps.

Comment: Thanks for this great tip but, how can I add my renderer function inside you recurringFunction in order to get and to render the positions?

Comment: I made an edit. You just need to add your code above dispatchQueue

Comment: That was the first thing i tried, but it doesn't render nor calculate any position at all: func recurringFunction(){ func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {...my code...} DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1/25) {self.recurringFunction()}}

Comment: I have edited, have a look. You dont need `func renderer(_ renderer:`

Comment: great!! that works as required! many thanks for your help, @alok-subedi

Comment: It's probably better to use a dispatch source rather than continuously enqueuing blocks, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsourcetimer